# When I do deep learning training, the GPU seems to stop working?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, distributed

```
   for images, targets in metric_logger.log_every(data_loader, print_freq, header):
    images = list(image.to(device) for image in images)
    targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]
    # a = True
    with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(enabled=scaler is not None):
        print('1:', device, torch.cuda.memory_allocated() / (1024 * 1024))
        loss_dict = model(images, targets)
        print('2:', device, torch.cuda.memory_allocated() / (1024*1024))
        losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
```

I have four gpus, but their output looks like 1: cuda:2 0.0, 2:cuda :2 0.0,cuda:0 586,2:cuda0 1509. To summarize, only the first GPU (CUDA0) works properly. Other Gpus (CUDA1, CUDA2, CUDA3) train very slowly in the early stages and run out of memory in the middle (normally they don't run out of memory).

Comment: Request help!!!

Comment: By the way, I used MPI parallel training